# Render model to frame buffer

Tags: c++, opengl

In my OpenGL program I want to render everything in memory. I don't want to render data to a window/screen. So I created a Frame Buffer. Next thing I want to do is to render a 3d model to that Frame Buffer.

I've downloaded the Assimp library to handle the loading of the models. I'm just not sure how to work with this. It looks like it is expecting you to draw everything directly to a window?

All I want to do right now is to load and draw that model to my Frame Buffer. That's basically all.

Any tips/advice on how to do this easily? Tips for another library (which may suit my needs better) are welcome too.

My code, where I want to draw to my frame buffer:

```
glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, fbo); // Bind our frame buffer for rendering
glPushAttrib(GL_VIEWPORT_BIT | GL_ENABLE_BIT); // Push our glEnable and glViewport states
glViewport(0, 0, window_width, window_height); // Set the size of the frame buffer view port

glClearColor (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Set the clear colour
glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear the depth and colour buffers
glLoadIdentity(); // Reset the modelview matrix


// RENDER 3D MODEL HERE....
// TEAPOT AS EXAMPLE
glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f); // Translate back 5 units
glRotatef(rotation_degree, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Rotate according to our rotation_degree value

//glFrontFace(GL_CW);
glutSolidTeapot(1.0f); // Render a teapot
//glFrontFace(GL_CCW);

int r = glGetError();
int s = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);



glPopAttrib(); // Restore our glEnable and glViewport states
glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0); // Unbind our texture
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assimp library is just a loader; it doesn't care whether you draw to an off-screen framebuffer or a window's backbuffer.

Try checking the return codes from **glGetError** and **glCheckFramebufferStatus**.

Comment: Thanks, i added that to my code. I also added a small snippet of code to my post where i'm trying to render a teapot. But glGetError gave me 1282. The frame buffer status was OK though. Guess i'll have to find out why i'm getting the glerror.

Answer (score 0):

> In my OpenGL program I want to render everything in memory. I don't want to render data to a window/screen. So I created a Frame Buffer. Next thing I want to do is to render a 3d model to that Frame Buffer.

Do you have a OpenGL context? I see that you're using GLUT. For with GLUT to get a OpenGL context you must create a window. Without a OpenGL context you can not create a Frame Buffer Object.

For you this means, that you can not make use of GLUT. But that's no big deal, because GLUT is just some library, a lot of people think it's something integral of OpenGL, which it is not.

I suggest you use a PBuffer for your offscreen rendering. In X11/GLX this is straightforward, but a bit tedious in Windows. In Windows you need to create a proxy window, to get a intermediate OpenGL context for the first extension loading phase, which you require to get access to the function to create a PBuffer; that proxy window is not required to be become visible however. Note that you cannot use a invisible window with a OpenGL context for off-screen rendering, because in that situation pixels will not pass the *pixel ownership test* and thus are not processed.